# How to fade in SDImageCache images

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently my images are just *popping* into view. I want them to fade in.

I have tried this, with no luck:

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
        [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:encodedString done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

            if (image){
                cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
            }else{
                [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString] placeholderImage:myImage completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

                    [imageCache storeImage:image forKey:encodedString];

                }];

                UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                imageView.alpha = 0;

                [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
                    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
                }];
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else block should look like follows:

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString]
                                    options:0
                                   progress:nil
                                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

                    [imageCache storeImage:image forKey:encodedString];
                    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                    imageView.alpha = 0;

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
                       imageView.alpha = 1.0;
                    }];
                }];
```

Comment: this doesn't work propperly I am getting errors with the last `}];` so I replaced it with `})];` and now images are being replaced with the wrong images

Comment: still shuffles the images!

Comment: Could you please provide image URL?

Comment: it is like this `NSString *link = [stringy stringByAppendingString: result[indexPath.row][@"image"]];
        NSString* encodedString = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
`

Comment: Try to log url and open it in web browser.

Comment: I mean that it is multiple images! it is a list of images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57861/discussion-between-sviatoslav-yakymiv-and-maximilian).

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

__weak typeof(UIImageView) *weakimgView = imgView;

```
    [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_photo.url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoIcon"] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

            [weakimgView setAlpha:0.4];

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

            weakimgView.image = image;
            [weakimgView setAlpha:1.0];


            [UIView commitAnimations];


    }];
```

Hope this will help you. happy Coding :)